# When you are going to console someone

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Imagine a close friend of you (A) has faced a loss recently and they are deeply sad. You arrange a gather-together and while you are chatting with your other friends suddenly you forget about your friend.
A common friend of you and your close friend (B) comes to you (who has noticed that "A" is crying in his privacy) and whereas "B" knows that you are a closer friend to "A", asks you to go beside him and console him. 
I was wondering if you could let me know whether in AmE the self-made sentence below sounds natural or not. If not, then please let me know how a native speaker would say the same thing in a natural way:

> - Go and sit beside him and console him a little.

Answer (score 4):

Your sentence is not wrong, and I don't think anyone would misunderstood your meaning. "Console" is a somewhat formal word though, and it sounds strange to "console a little". After all, why would you only want to comfort someone a little bit? It's also a command, not a request, which might bother some people, and the location is really unnecessary unless it is really important to actually sit next to the person.

```
I think you should go comfort him
```

Is more concise and less demanding.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds unnatural in conversational English. They could say:

- A looks sad, maybe you should go talk to him
- I saw A crying, he could use some cheering up
- Could you comfort A for me?
- A needs a shoulder to cry on right now
- Go sit and talk with A; he looks sad